# Table design for scheduling calls

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql, database-design

Say you have a call center that needs to do X amount of calls in a given day. Each customer can be called for Y amount of products that they need to pay. The business would like to assign the calls to the operators at the start of the day and then be able to evaluate daily the results of those calls.

For those reasons, I'm thinking about deviding the structure into two with one table with the customers and another with the products.
What I am having problem with is deciding the primary key to put in the master scheduling table. Since there will be a good number of records every day, part of me wants to write the data in sequence for each day:

```
DateOfRecords   date      
Sequence        int    
OperatorID      int    
CustomerID      int
```

Rest of the columns…

With DateOfRecords and sequence being the primary key.

I know that many recommend establishing an integer as a primary key and then index on the other columns. Again, my question comes because of the amount of records to be saved daily given the fact that this will be a historic table.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your question here exactly? *"Any suggestions?"* is far to broad to be answerable by itself. Is it simply "Is `DateofRecords` and `Sequence` a good composite Primary key candidate?"

Comment: if `sequence` is autonumeric why you need `date` as part of PK ?

Comment: @Larnu I am sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my question. Basically I am asking for a recomendation on how to design the table.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Sequence wouldn't be autonumeric. It would be created by an app. What we are trying to avoid is having one primary key as a single numeric column and then having problems later on when there are millions of records later on.

Comment: `trying to avoid is having one primary key as a single numeric` that isn't a problem not matter how millions rows you have. That is the recommended approach. Letting the app handling the sequence can have problems because you have to handle concurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You can have just one clustered key per table. In most cases - but not necessarily - this will be the *primary key*. There are some things to consider:

- The clustered key is the physical table itself. It includes all columns automatically.
- The best clustered key is one which will never get fragmented (e.g. a sequence). The worst clustered key is an ordinary Guid.
- If there is a clustered key, it will serve as a *look-up* for other indexes. if the clustered key is bad (e.g. fragmenting), other indexes will get an impact.
- If your clustered index is running in fragmentation, you will have to repair this from time to time. This needs a huge physical shifting of data and should be avoided if possible.

*Normal* indexes are rather slim. They cover - to put it easy - a sorted list, together with the PK for a fast access to the actual row (with all the columns).

So - to put all this together: You should have a clustered primary key index using a non-fragmenting column. Additionally you can use as many indexes as you need, covering (and including) columns you need in queries.

There *can be* good reasons for multi-column PKs, Sometimes this *can be* the best choice. But the general advise is: Use a sequence as the (clustered) PK and place additional indexes to support your queries.

This will not be the absolutely fastest approach in each and any case, but a very good *serves-for-all* approach.

And one more point: Many programming approaches are best supported, if the tables have some things in common. E.g. an `ID` column or something like `InsertDateTime`. This allows for more generic programming approaches.

### UPDATE: To add to your comment...

In a comment above you state: *"...and then having problems later on when there are millions of records later on"*. Such issues are best solved with partitioned tables, filtered indexes and/or archiving strategies...

### UPDATE2: Good to think about *sargability*...

In your question you write *"Since there will be a good number of records every day, part of me wants to write the data in sequence for each day"*. Most operations you do against a column will break the usage of indexes (read about *sargability*). But a `CAST()` of a `DATETIME` to a `DATE` will allow to filter for calendar days without performance losses. Something like `WHERE CAST(InsertDateTime AS DATE) ='20190909'` will work lightning fast with an index on `InsertDateTime`.

Comment: My goal was to get some insight from the crowd of what did they think about that approach. Thanks for the explanation and for taking the time to reply. I'm thinking of going with the unsigned integer.